# Cannot stop wpautop from messing up my plug-in output

Tags: plugin-development, wp-autop

I have a plug-in that embeds some javascript. I've tried using remove_filter() to stop wpautop in every way recommend and still can't get wordpress to stop wrapping my `<script></script>` tags with with `<p>` tags like this `<p><script></script></p>`

I tried adding the following to both the short code php and also in the functions.php

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt',     'wpautop' );
```

Comment: Please provide the code that you have already tried.

Comment: just modified the question with the code

Answer (score 1):

Here is one idea

```
add_filter('the_content','remove_stuff',99,1);

function remove_stuff($content){
    $from=array("<p><script>","</script></p>");
    $to=array("<script>","</script>");
    $content=str_replace($from,$to,$content);
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: excellent idea, but it didn't have any impact. On further examination it appears WP is just adding a <p> tag before <script> and no closing </p>. At any rate, this code didn't stop it. The only way I've been able to totally prevent it is by tweaking wp itself and changing wpautop to just return without making changes